# Are there problems previewing questions and answers in latex with IE8?

Tags: support, status-completed

When viewing questions with latex formatting, the page doesn't dislay to start with, and has a yellow icon with an exclamation mark at the bottom right with the error codes:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6)
> Timestamp: Wed, 2 Mar 2011 01:01:17 UTC
>
> Message: No such element
> Line: 35
> Char: 3
> Code: 0
> URI: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/content/js/third-party/MathJax/MathJax.js

If I refresh the page it displays correctly without the error code.

But I can't do this when trying to preview my answer because it wipes my answer clean.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: I had the same problems too. Even when it rendered it was painfully slow. I switched to FireFox for browsing Math.SE.

Comment: @moron, thanks, I'll have to look into the other browsers then.

Comment: Do people still use IE?

Comment: @swivaram, 50% use firefox, 25% use IE and Chrome: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: Interesting to note that 26.6% of the internet users are still in the stone age.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is resolved in MathJax 1.1 and 1.1a? IE7 is our absolute minimum supported browser, but IE8 should work fine.